# How to set compiler flags in Compile Sources to omit a file from a build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I want to set the Debug flag in Compile Sources. But I'm not sure what the right way is. I don't want to compile some files when I'm building for release.

Other Swift Flags screenShot:

[image: Other Swift Flags screenShot]

Compile Sources screenShot:

[image: Compile Sources screenShot]

Comment: Double click on the row it will open a dialog, click on (+) sign in the bottom and add flag.

Comment: @JackLawrence Thank you, That's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "Other Swift Flags" in your target's Build Settings to `-D DEBUG` so you can use the "#if/#else/#endif" preprocessor macros.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to compile whole things when I'm building for release. For example, the TinyColsoneCotroller.swift file will not be compiled when building release

Comment: I can also wrap the TinyConsoleController using the #if DEBUG #endif. But I think it's not clear. I want to divide files by Compiler Flags if I can